# How to reflect types with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've successfully used [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/automap.html) with tables, but I could not figure out how to reflect types, such as enums. I'm using postgres 9.4

Comment: I think your question is unclear. BTW there are many PostgreSQL specific mappings:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=enum#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base
Also, there's a Enum type: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=enum#enum-types

Comment: Thanks, Pedro. I was able to get what I want using `get_enums()` from your links. You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy have specific mappings for PostgreSQL databases, including enums:

[SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=enum#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base)

[Enum mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=enum#enum-types)